# How to achieve kendoui combobox auto-complete reverse look-up when editing?

Tags: kendo-ui, edit, record, kendo-combobox

Here is the scenario:

I have a kendo combobox and it is working as it should for adding records. It will look up records from it's data source as the user types, and assign the ID of the selected record to the FK field in the record being edited. I have paging in the datasource set to 30 records and this works nicely.

Now when I edit a record, the FK ID is bound to the combobox and it then looks up the record so it can display the text for it. Perfect. However if the record bound to the combobox has an ID that is not in the first page of data returned by the comboboxs auto-complete datasource, it just shows the FK ID instead of the text for the record in the combobox widget UI.

How can I get the combobox to look up the record by ID to display the text for it on, when loading an edit form?

Or is there a better solution? Can I somehow bind the text to the combobox for records being edited if I include it in the load record data?

Thank you for your time,

Regards,

Scott

Comment: If for the combobox you want to search over the full combobox auto-complete datasource, why do you use paging? why do not return all the results?

Comment: because without the paging, if you don't type anything and you just press the button on the combobox, and there are thousands of records, in the table, won't it attempt to load them all?

Comment: Ok... in that case I'm not getting how you can pick a value that is not in the first page. If you type "John" and you get more than 10 records (lets say that pagesize is 10) that means that there are more than then Johns in your DB. How do you choose which? How is it possible that the "correct" John is not in the first page?

Comment: Well either John has a last name that you have concatenated into your text field SQL, and you continue typing that to narrow it down, or you get a list of 10 johns with no last name, and there is no way to tell which one is which anyway. Like even if you did get 30 or 100 or all the Johns with no last name, how would you know which one to select anyway? You would have no idea.... really you just want to get a short list that narrows down as you type, and provide enough data in the items in then list that they described themselves in a way that's easy for users to determine which one they want.

Comment: As you say _list that narrows down as you type_, why not using kendoAutocomplete? It seems to me that it fits better to what you need and you will not have paging once you narrow down to 1 result and hopefully will not have that "paging" (side)effect that you describe in your original question.

Comment: Yes mate... I first tried to use the AutoComplete widget, thinking it would be the way to go for sure... but couldn't I find a way to bind the ID to the FK ID field.  It just bound the text field.  I couldn't find an example anywhere of basic scenario of autocomplete with FK ID as value and text field as display and binding the FK ID to the record being edited in the kendo doco or on the web.  Is there one?

Comment: The combobox has a search function that I can use to look up a specific record, but the issue is that is that it opens the popup and takes the focus.  The combobox really needs a loadRecord function  that can look up a specific record without the popup or taking the focus, for the scenario of editing a record.